# What computers can read MS-DOS hard drives?

Tags: hard-drive, x86

I have a G|Raid External Hard drive that is formatted as MS-DOS. I verified that by checking the file format on a Mac (it says MS-DOS). I know Macs can read APFS, but I tried plugging it into a Windows laptop and it could not be read.

I Googled some more and there was some mention of x86-computers being able to read it. Would I have to buy an x86-computer to access this data?

Comment: We need more details about the disk : Exact model and a photo of the cable and the and connector.

Comment: You can do this with a DOS virtual machine and a floppy drive or bus connected CDRom drive. I have this and have done it

Comment: MSDOS format is probably going to be FAT16 or FAT32. "Putting into a laptop and cannot be read" may mean "a secondary hard drive that windows doesn't recocgnize" or it may mean "the only HDD in the laptop and it won't boot". Please clarify this.

Comment: Or it could mean that the disk works and is seen as a proper removable hard disk and simply is not being automatically mounted. A screenshot of Disk Management might be useful. To open Disk Management, right-click the Start button and select Disk Management.

Comment: As a note "x86" is the type of processor used in nearly every normal Windows PC.

Comment: The biggest problem I see here might be the RAID because RAID controllers can add there own metadata at the front of the drive preventing it from being seen as a normal drive.  MSDOS uses FAT16 which virtual any PC can read and x86 or x64 has no bearing on reading it.  The size of a single FAT16 partition is limited to 2GB.  If you used RAID 0 spanning and not RAID 1 mirroring then both drives have to be connected as either drive by itself is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most OSes can read simple FAT format disks. That a Mac decided it should be called MS-DOS doesn't actually really tell us what the format actually is. MS-DOS is not a disk format, it's an operating system - but, yes, that's what Apple calls it. It should, however, qualify that in brackets after, as FAT32, FAT16 etc.

[image]

[image]

Macs don't like FAT formatted drives with non-standard parameters & will often fail to read them, so the fact that it can really does say it's a fairly standard FAT format.